# SaveVideo annotated labelized with Tensorflow Object detection

Tags: tensorflow, video, object-detection

I have a tensorflow object detection video annotated script. When i launch the python code it launch a screen and we see on video the annotated labels on objects detected. I want save this annotated video to a new video (because i want to see this video later).

Any Idea? i am novice in python and tensorflow i use this tuto EdjeElectronics multiple annotated video windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I've done like this

```
# Open video file
video = cv2.VideoCapture(PATH_TO_VIDEO)

#float
width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

print(width)
height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)) 
print(height)
fps = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
print(fps)
#size = Size(width, height)
fourcc = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC)
print(fourcc)
#create video file
```

videoFile=cv2.VideoWriter('savedVideo.mp4',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','P','4','V'),fps, 
           (width,height))
    ...
            cv2.imwrite("newVideo/frame%d.jpg" % count, frame)
        videoFile.write(frame)